# How to upload a jar to bintray with maven

Tags: maven, bintray

I'm trying to use bintray to upload a maven package (jar) to Maven Central Repository but I can't find any documentation or instructions to do that. So how to get started on bintray upload process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how to upload jars to bintray:

http://veithen.github.io/2013/05/26/github-bintray-maven-release-plugin.html